# How can resolve ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED accessing my Laravel app from another PC?

Tags: laravel

[**image package.json**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C25p5.png)login:15

```
   GET http://[::1]:5173/@vite/client net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
   GET http://[::1]:5173/resources/js/app.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
   GET http://[::1]:5173/resources/css/app.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I hosted it on a local server using xampp, inside the server it runs and works very well, but I want to access it outside the server on another machine and it returns this error. I tried http://ip_server/my_aplication/public/login

Answer (score -1):

Is that vite? I think you should run

npm run dev

Before open the project in your browser

Comment: npm run dev in production mode?

Comment: I ran npm run dev outside the server it doesn't work

Comment: Open package.json and see what command to run in local

Comment: please check the image on top is my package.json

Comment: What error that coming when you do "npm run dev" in your local? It should be making your project can be access in localhost:5173

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).